# Number of arguments in Tkinter classes

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, tkinter

relative noob here! I'm running 2.7, if that helps.

I'm trying to call a function defined in my main application class in a different function (I think that's called inheritance?) But I keep having problems with the number of args I put into my function!

Here's the function (is it called a method? if not, what's a method) I'm trying to call:

```
def student_list_updater(self, list):
    self.StudentListDisplay.delete(0, END)
    for student in list:
        self.StudentListDisplay.insert(END, student)
```

And here's the function I'm calling it in (it's inheriting student_list_updater, right?):

```
def OnRemoveClick(self, student_list_updater):
    self.student_list_updater = student_list_updater
    index = self.StudentListDisplay.curselection()
    index = int(index[0])
    del student_list_temp[index]
    self.student_list_updater(student_list_temp)
```

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little difficult to understand your question without more of the code, but hopefully this answer points you in the right direction.

First, to clarify, methods are just functions that can be accessed through an instance of a class, so yes, these are methods, but they're also functions--don't get too hung up on it. Next, I don't think inheritance is necessary here--inheritance will be one class inheriting attributes from another, and I believe all of your methods are only in one class (correct me if I'm mistaken).

Now, as to your code: it's giving you an error that one of your methods takes a number of arguments, and you gave it a different number. Well, to me, it looks like you only need to pass one argument for this whole process: `student_list_temp` to `student_list_updater()`. Once again, I can't say for sure that this will solve your problems, based on the lack of code you posted, but this might work:

```
def student_list_updater(self, studentlist): #change list to studentlist,
    self.StudentListDisplay.delete(0, END)   #Python already has a list() method
    for student in studentlist:
        self.StudentListDisplay.insert(END, student)

def OnRemoveClick(self): #Remove student_list_updater from the args, it has no value
    #self.student_list_updater = student_list_updater #this doesn't do anything
    index = self.StudentListDisplay.curselection() #This part I can't really comment on
    index = int(index[0])                          #without knowing the contents of the
    del student_list_temp[index]                   #Listbox and student_list_temp,
    self.student_list_updater(student_list_temp)   #but this should call student_list_updater()
                                                   #and update the Listbox if it's working
```

The last thing I want to point out is how you call `OnRemoveClick()` will probably change. If you're calling it from a Button, it would look like this:

```
self.btn = Button(self, text='GO', command=self.OnRemoveClick)
```

Note that you're not passing any arguments to it.

Hope that helps. You also might want to take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html and https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html to clear up any classes and functions questions you might have.

Comment: Thanks a **LOT**, man. I'm glad that I just have to tidy up my code - I was worried that I was missing something huge. But I never would have found that out without your help, which was very clear. even though I wasn't. Thanks a bunch!